# Exporting blockly to google's kit

Tags: blockly

I created a blockly app with google's blockly workspace creator. I created a workspace and a bunch of new blocks. But... when i export the files,they export as .xml files,but how can i create a google page with my workspace and blocks? I mean, i downloaded google blockly kit (the one with files "appengine","blocks","core","demos" etc.) for web. But .xml files are not compatible with the kit (or i think). How can i do it?

I searched a lot,finding a lot of unuseful answers. Can someone help me?

P.S. Sorry for my bad english,i'm italian.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review our SO Question Checklist to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Please paste a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the code you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Most often the Blockly XML is embedded within the HTML with an `id=".."` attribute, and a CSS rule that sets those to `display: none`. In this case, the XML DOM is extracted using `getElementById`. You can find many examples of this style in the Blockly demos.

My preferred solution is to use a JavaScript string constant. If you can get by without using Internet Explorer, a multiline template literal makes this easy:

```
const myToolbox = `
    <xml>
      <category name="Logic">
        <block type="controls_if" />
        <block type="logic_compare" />
      </category>
    </xml>`;
```

Otherwise, embedded it in JavaScript takes little more finesse:

```
const myToolbox =
    '<xml>' +
      '<category name="Logic">' +
        '<block type="controls_if" />' +
        '<block type="logic_compare" />' +
      '</category>' +
    '</xml>';
```